# Retrieving a list of tagged output cells and a list of variables from various Notebooks into a new Notebook

Tags: import, notebooks, cells

The table below provides the information needed to formulate my question: how can I gather a selected number of tagged output cells and variables in a new notebook?

[image]

I have two notebooks `nb1` and `nb2`. These notebooks have tagged `input cells` uniquely named such as `tc11` and `tc21` in `nb1`; similarly, `tc41` and `tc53` in `nb2`. In the 3rd column of the table, I give two sample lists of the `output cells` that I want to gather in a new Notebook (`newNB`). For example, `{tc11, tc46}` and `{tc31, tc53, tc46}` are the lists that I like to bring into `newNB`.

In `nb1` and `nb2`, I also have variables to be brought into `newNB`. Examples of variable lists include `{var11, var22}` and `{var21, var12}`.

I like to have a `Mathematica` function such as:

```
gatherF[lstNB_, lstOUT_, lstVAR_]:=
```

with three arguments: list of notebooks  (`lstNB`), list of tagged output cells (`lstOUT`), and list of variables (`lstVAR`).

Note that tagged output cells inherit tagged input cells, meaning that input and output cells have the same name. I only want the tagged output cells, not input cells.

Comment: What do you mean by "variables to be brought into newNB"?

Comment: @Kuba: A variable is a calculation done in a notebook, such as `x=y+3` where I call `x` as a variable. In my real case, a tagged cell includes a `Manipulate[...]` and I want to get the output from the `Manipulate`. Whereas a variable is defined out of the `Manipulate`.

Comment: @Kuba: My explanation of a variable is not complete. I do not want to get the value assigned to `x` but I want `x` variable to be active in the new notebook so that I can use it in other calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if it fits your needs:

```
notebooks = {(*__NotebookObject*)};
tags = {(*__String*)};
styles = {"Output"};


notebooks //
  Map[Cells[#, CellStyle -> styles, CellTags -> tags] &] //
  Flatten //
  Map[NotebookRead] //
  CreateDocument
```

Comment: I run your code with an example. There is no error nor warnings. The only output I get is a `NotebookObject[...]`. Does this `NotebookObject` include the outputs I am after?` If so, how can I open this `NotebookObject`? Thank you very much for the code.

Comment: @Tugrul The point notebook object should correspond to a newly created notebook window. Did it not appear? What is your os and mma version?

Comment: No, there was no window open. My OS is Windows and MMA version 11.3

Comment: @TugrulTemel That is weird, does this create a window for you: `CreateDocument[]`?

Comment: Yes, it creates a window including only `Print[...]`, which is something I like to print. But this window is just showing that `CreateDocument[...]` has worked, however, I do not see any printout result.

Comment: @TugrulTemel sorry, hard to say anything without examples. The new notebook should contain a list of output cells which were tagged appropriately in associated notebooks.

Comment: I will give an example soon and edit the question. Thanks for your time.